# Can you give me a Programming problem in java

Tags: java

I am learning java on my own. I have books to read. but i feel i am not really coding anything significant . Can you guys give me any programming problem that would really help me get more practical experience rather than a theoretical experience with java ?

Appreciate it.

silverkid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

[Martyr2’s Mega Project List](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/78802-martyr2s-mega-project-ideas-list/)

Comment: i think thats a very nice category wise list of problems ... thanks a lot

Comment: yes .. and the most important thing for your future programming skills (doesn't matter what programming language you use) is to try to do some real small projects (and not just mathematic problems/puzzles/...) because they will give you right perspective on what you have accomplished so far and what are the areas you don't know and have to learn in a future...

Comment: I completely agree. It's also worth implementing small games. To make learning programming more fun, it's best to work on projects which have more rewards for less work, that at the same time cover many aspects of programming.

Answer (score 9):

Many people learn new languages by solving problems from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/).

To give you some examples, here are the 10 first problems in the project:

- [Add all the natural numbers below one thousand that are multiples of 3 or 5.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=1)
- [Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the Fibonacci sequence which do not exceed four million.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2)
- [Find the largest prime factor of a composite number.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=3)
- [Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=4)
- [What is the smallest number divisible by each of the numbers 1 to 20?](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=5)
- [What is the difference between the sum of the squares and the square of the sums?](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=6)
- [Find the 10001<sup>st</sup> prime.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=7)
- [Discover the largest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=8)
- [Find the only Pythagorean triplet, {*a*, *b*, *c*}, for which *a* + *b* + *c* = 1000.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=9)
- [Calculate the sum of all the primes below two million.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=10)

Comment: Just a warning to people going this route: Project Euler is pretty much exclusively mathematician porn.

Comment: very helpful site too... thks a lot

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to put *an idea* out here for you from my own experiences.

Whilst studying I was given the task of creating a Client/Sever chat application, I found it really interesting and there are plenty of obvious ways you can extend the program to better your ability.

For instance, start with a basic server and client simply sending text to one another.  And then advance to having users (from a database perhaps) who have to log in to the application. You can make it as simple and as complicated as you wish.

Hope this helps.

Tony

Comment: thanks tony... I have decided to take up this problem

Comment: Good to hear :) Thanks. Another refinement to keep in mind is transferring binary information, such as users sending each other files/pictures, it's not as difficult as it may seem. You can also do a user list with states (away, busy). The further you get into the project, start to work more with OOP.

Good luck SilverKid!

Answer (score 2):

Java exercises:
http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+exercise

Java examples:
http://www.exampledepot.com/

What area of Java programming are you interested in? Web, device, desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Sure Why Not, [Here it is : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: looks like a tutorial rather than programming problems page.

Comment: @silverkid it is useful for your purpose

Comment: yes looks a very helpful resource.. thanks